# What is the equivalent to jQuery REST request promises like .success and .error in AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

It's a pretty self explanatory question. I'm seeing a few ways that people handle errors, I'm wondering if one way is recommended over another, and what is the best practice.

Comment: Angular $http provider returns promise, which gives ability to subscribe on error event, because promise resolves in 3 ways: success, error and then. So... what a question?

Comment: I thought I saw people building custom promises to handle the simple things like success and error, but I guess this is the way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: My question is: Is there a different way to do it when using a factory method? Because the examples on the $http docs use something like $http.get().success(); whereas my usage is more like User.get(); Could I do something like Uset.get().success().error(); for example? @dt0xff

Comment: You can return `$http.get` promise from `User.get` method. But if you want to make promise resolve preprocessed result(like you want to make special object for `User`), there might be possibility of using different promise.

Answer (score 0):

Angular $http provider returns promise, which gives ability to subscribe on error event, because promise resolves in 3 ways: success, error and then.

So it is common to use this promise inside and outside - you can return it from service and use in the controller.

Don't create new promise if you have one, which resolves in the moment you need.